# Can a non-zero symmetric matrix have only zero eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know that a non-zero symmetric 2×2 matrix can't have only zero eigenvalues ( a zero eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity 2), since such a matrix should have complex off diagonal entries to satisfy both trace and determinant being zero. I'm guessing if this is the case for the general case of any non-zero n×n symmetric matrix.

Comment: It's also true for any symmetric matrix. It's similar to a diagonal matrix with it's eigenvalues put at the diagonal.

Comment: Thanks. Helping me to look at the problem from the perspective of spectral decomposition made it completely clear for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because then it is a **nilpotent** *symmetric* matrix, and since symmetric matrics are diagonalizable and the only diagonalizable *nilpotent* matrix is the zero matrix, we'd get a contradicition to "non-zero matrix"

Answer (score 1):

A big classic is to show that if $A$ nilpotent then $\operatorname{tr}(A^k)=0$.

Another classic is to show that $\mathcal N(A)=\operatorname{tr}(^tAA)$ is a norm on square matrices.

If $A$ is nilpotent and symmetric, these two combine and $\mathcal{N}(A)=\operatorname{tr}(^tAA)=\operatorname{tr}(A^2)=0$ so $A=0$.

Comment: The first one is an iff argument if we add " for all $\;k\in\Bbb N\;$"